# Jquery Show and hide on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, animation, hide, show

I am trying to create a image to show after a 900px scroll but hide when it has reached 700px

It works on scroll down but when im not sure how to hide it after a certain about amount of pixels

here is my code.

```
    $(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 900) {
        $('.bottom-signup').fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
        $('.bottom-signup').fadeOut(700);
    }

});
```

Thanks guys 
see demo

http://jsfiddle.net/uhUWC/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if i got your question correctly.

```
    $(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 700 && y<900) {
        $('.bottom-signup').fadeIn(1000);
    } 
    else {
        $('.bottom-signup').fadeOut(700);
    }

});
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i have created a fiddle, the button disappear when you stop scrolling, i need it to stop then disappear on scroll up http://jsfiddle.net/uhUWC/

Comment: What you are trying to do ? also Check this article   http://codewithlogic.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/smooth-scrolling-effect-in-javascript-using-jquery/